# Python: Saving parts of str to an array

Tags: python, variables, search

I'm having an issue in python. I have a variable set as the output of a command, and this output is many lines long. lets just say for simplicity sake this is the ouput of the command I have issues that is now stored in variable 'OUTPUT':

FRU 0_2_3 enclosure 1
FRU 0_2_4 enclosure 1
FRU 0_2_5 enclosure 1
FRU 0_2_6 enclosure 1

and now i wish to search that variable and store only the part of the lines that says #_ #_#. 
NOTE: I do not want to use a text file for this

```
import re
disks=[]
i=0
OUTPUT=fbeclicommand("li -all") #This is the command on some exe that will gather the output and save it to this variable.
if re.search("\d{1,3}_\d{1,3}_\d{1,3}",OUTPUT):
    disks[i]=OUTPUT
    i+=1
```

I basically want to store only the number part in the array and do it for all 4 or however many numbers there are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split it by the space and get the number which is at index 1. Also you can use the `.append` method on the list to push it to the array instead of using indicies and setting it at a certain index. Same affect, less code!

```
import re
disks=[]

OUTPUT = '''
FRU 0_2_3 enclosure 1
FRU 0_2_4 enclosure 1
FRU 0_2_5 enclosure 1
FRU 0_2_6 enclosure 1
'''
#OUTPUT=fbeclicommand("li -all") #This is the command on some exe that will gather the output and save it to this variable.
OUTPUTSplit= OUTPUT.split('\n')
for line in OUTPUTSplit:
    if re.search("\d{1,3}_\d{1,3}_\d{1,3}", line):
        disks.append(line.split(' ')[1])

print disks
```

#### Output

```
['0_2_3', '0_2_4', '0_2_5', '0_2_6']
```

Answer (score 0):

I sort of think that if you're already using regexes, you should just go ahead and use capturing groups:

```
match = re.search("\d{1,3}_\d{1,3}_\d{1,3}", output_line):
if match is not None:
    disks.append(match.group())
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html